# What is the best way to visualize subsurface drillhole and borehole geology data within ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d, visualisation, geology

I've heard some folks in mining are using Target for ArcGIS extension by Geosoft to
visualize and analyze subsurface drillhole and borehole geology data within ArcGIS.

Does anyone have experience with this tool? What are your impressions? What is the learning curve like? Is there any other comparable extension for ArcGIS with similar functionality?

Comment: Have u got a link to this Target extension?

Comment: http://www.geosoft.com/pinfo/software/targetarcgis/index.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have worked with Target for ArcGIS and it is in fact a great tool. It takes some time getting used to it, but it is a simple tool that can produce great results.

The workflow for construction profiles, etc. is a bit funky, different from what you might be used to in ArcGIS, but other than that its great. The other extensions from Geosoft (geochemistry for arcgis) are very well built too, and can give you good results.

Target really shines when you use it with a database holding the data for you, and from what I know it's also programmable - Geosoft has an API for it.

The downside it is it's price. Around R$ 12.000,00 , the last time I checked it (around 6.000 U$) in Brazil.

Comment: Thanks George. Exactly what I needed to know. Great input about the 'built' quality. This is very important, considering the price. The company I work for invested too much money into "non-mainstream" software that is just too flaky. Great info. Thanks.  Geosoft offers 3 training courses 2 for Target 1 for Geochemistry. Do you think they're worth taking or is the documentation sufficient.

Comment: Jakub, if in your organisation someone has experience with Geosoft Target, they can teach others. The real issue is that Target is a software full of surprises that might take you a while to figure it out by yourself, so perhaps it's interesting to take the courses if NO ONE has experience with it. I did not take any courses, and learned by myself, with the help of someone who took the course. It worked for me :P.